# delete request ajax jquery don't function

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, controller, delete-record

I'm trying to do a DELETE request with Ajax, but it doesn't function,I receive an internal error, but i can't see the problem, can you help me?

this is the partial code of javascript:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/actors/remover',
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: JSON.stringify(movie),
    traditional:true,
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(result) {...},
    error: function(result){...}
});
```

and here the code of my controller:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/actors/remover", method = RequestMethod.DELETE)//TODO, elimina un attore dal db
public boolean remove(@PathVariable("movie") int movie) {
    System.out.println("Attori da cancellare");
    serv.deleteActors(movie);
    return true;
}//remove
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Problems i see in your code:

1. `dataType:'json'` is used if you get your response as a json object.
2. At the backend you are not producing `json` at all but there is a `boolean`.
3. You have to use `contentType:'application/json'`.
4. And there is no need to use `traditional:true`.

---

So i suggest you to use this:

```
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://localhost:8080/actors/remover',
    type: 'DELETE',
    data: {movie:movie}, //<-----this should be an object.
    contentType:'application/json',  // <---add this
    dataType: 'text',                // <---update this
    success: function(result) {...},
    error: function(result){...}
});
```

Comment: i used this solution and it functions:

Comment: $.ajax({
          url: 'http://localhost:8080/actors/' + movieId,
          type: 'DELETE',
          success: function(result) {...}